# Using accessors in Objective-C for each loop

Tags: objective-c, loops, collections, foreach, accessor

I was wondering if there would be any difference in performance between the following code snippets in Objective-C:

```
NSArray *theArray = [self someArray];

for (NSObject *obj in theArray)
{
    // do something
}
```

versus

```
for(NSObject *obj in [self someArray])
{
    // do something
}
```

I assumed that the latter would compile down to the same as the former, but a colleague of mine argued that the latter used the accessor [self someArray] every iteration.

Does anyone with some serious Objective-C knowledge know if there is a performance hit from using the accessor method in the loop header?  The collections I'm using would have many hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Put an NSLog  in your `someArray` method and check how many times it gets logged?

Comment: The accessor method is automatically generated by the @synthesize directive, although you're right, I could easily do one by hand to test it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  The accessor is only called once.  A trivial test proves it:

```
@import Foundation;
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface M : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@end

@implementation M
- (NSArray *)array { NSLog(@"moo"); return @[ @1, @2, @3 ]; }
@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        M *m = [M new];

        for (NSNumber *n in m.array) {
                NSLog(@"%@", n);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The output of this test program is:

```
2015-11-23 11:54:48.937 a.out[93427:5794850] moo
2015-11-23 11:54:48.939 a.out[93427:5794850] 1
2015-11-23 11:54:48.939 a.out[93427:5794850] 2
2015-11-23 11:54:48.939 a.out[93427:5794850] 3
```